# Convexity of a function depending on value of parameters

Tags: convex-analysis

Check out convexity of a function $J(u)=cu^r$, $J:[a,b]\rightarrow R$,
 $0<a<b<\infty$, depending on values of parameters $c,r\in R$.

I know a **definition** of a convexity:
"Function J,defined on convex interval U, is convex on U if $J(\alpha u + (1-\alpha) v)\leq \alpha J(u) + (1-\alpha) J(v)$
and I know theorems:

**Theorem 1**
Let U be non-empty convex set in $R^n$ and $J\in C^1(U)$.
Function $J$ is convex if and only if

$\langle J'(u)-J'(v),u-v\rangle \geq 0$ for all $u,v\in U$

**Theorem 2**
Let U be convex set in $R^n$ with non-empty interior. Let $J\in C^2(U)$.
Function $J$ is convex on U if and only if
$\langle J''(u) ξ,ξ\rangle \geq 0$ for all $u\in U$ and all $ξ\in R^n$.

But I don't know what to use.
I tried in 3 ways:
Using **Theorem 1**

$u,v\in [a,b]$.
$\langle J'(u)-J'(v),u-v\rangle = \langle cru^{r-1}-crv^{r-1},u-v\rangle = cr\langle u^{r-1}-v^{r-1},u-v\rangle = cr \sqrt[2] {|u^{r-1}-v^{r-1}|^2+|u-v|^2}$
If this is ok, then J is convex if
1) $c,r\geq 0$
2) $c,r\leq 0$

Using **Theorem 2**:

$J'(u)=rcu^{r-1}$
$J''(u)=r(r-1)cu^{r-2}$

$\langle J''(u) ξ,ξ\rangle=\langle r(r-1)cu^{r-2} ξ,ξ\rangle$
and I don't know what now.

Using **definition**

I should show that
$J(\alpha u + (1-\alpha) v)\leq \alpha J(u) + (1-\alpha) J(v)$
for all $u,v\in [a,b]$
So, let $u,v\in [a,b]$.
$J(\alpha u + (1-\alpha) v)=c(\alpha u + (1-\alpha) v)^r$
And I don't know what to do now.

Comment: The second derivative is a scalar. What conditions make it positive?

Comment: 1) if $r\in [0,1)$, than c must be $\leq 0$  
2) if $r\geq 1$ than c must be $\geq 0$  
3) if $r<0$, c must be $\geq 0$  
  
Is this ok?

Comment: So, I can write  $⟨r(r−1)cu^{r−2}ξ,ξ⟩=r(r−1)cu^{r−2}\langle ξ,ξ⟩$ ?

Comment: @copper.hat why second derivative is scalar?

Comment: Because the function $J:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ (that is, the domain is a scalar).

Comment: why first derivative is not scalar then? And what about 3rd derivative? It would be $0$ then?

Comment: All derivatives are scalars if the domain & range consist of scalars!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $J''(u) = cr(r-1)u^{r-2}$.

Then just work through the possibilities:

If $r=0$, then $J(u)$ is a constant, hence convex and concave.

If $c =0$, then $J(u)$ is a constant, hence convex and concave.

If $r=1$, then $J$ is convex and concave, regardless of $c$.

If $r > 1$ and $c > 0$, then $J''(u) \ge 0$, hence convex.

If $r > 1$ and $c < 0$, then $J''(u) < 0$, hence concave (and not convex).

If $0 < r < 1$ and $c > 0$, then $J''(u) < 0$, hence concave (and not convex).

If $0 < r < 1$ and $c < 0$, then $J''(u) > 0$, hence convex.

If $r <0$ and $c >0$, then $J''(u) > 0$, hence convex.

If $r <0$ and $c <0$, then $J''(u) < 0$, hence concave (and not convex).